# detect duplicate value in for each loop php

Tags: php

```
    foreach( array_combine( $ContentArray, $fileDateArray ) as $Content_Individual_Filename => $File_Individual_Date )
    {
    }
```

I want to detect duplicate date in `$File_Individual_Date`. if duplicate date/value then run if condition otherwise run else. for example

```
    foreach( array_combine( $ContentArray, $fileDateArray ) as $Content_Individual_Filename => $File_Individual_Date )
    {
         if( $File_Individual_Date === duplicateValue )
         {
         }
         else
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `array_count_values()` to create a lookup table before you run through the loop.

```
$a = array_combine($ContentArray, $fileDateArray);
$counts = array_count_values($a);
foreach($a as $Content_Individual_Filename => $File_Individual_Date) {
     if($counts[$File_Individual_Date] > 1) { // has duplicate
     } else { // unique value
     }
}
```